# jQuery .val() returns undefined for radio button

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to get the checked radio button value in jQuery. But it returns value as 'undefined'. I searched solution for this issue but nothing works for me.

My HTML Code.

```
<label><input type="radio" class="service" name="service" id="all-service" value="all-service"> All Service</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" class="service" name="service" id="electrician" value="Electrician"> Electrician</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" class="service" name="service" id="painter" value="Painter"> Painter</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" class="service" name="service" id="photo and video coverage" value="Photo and Video Coverage"> Photo and Video Coverage</label>
```

My Jquery code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".service").change(function() {
        alert($(".service :checked").val());
    });
});
```

Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9o6uj4L/) for my problem..

Comment: It should be `".service:checked"`. Space means that you search through descendants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should not be any space between classname and `:checked` attribute

```
 $(".service").change(function() {
        alert($(".service:checked").val());
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9o6uj4L/1/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".service").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9o6uj4L/3/).

Comment: this is better approach

Comment: if it's unchecked then ? I thnk user wants only selected value.

Comment: @nirmal In this case you can not uncheck it without checking the other button. AFAIK, you can not uncheck radio without help of some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Remove an extra space bewteen `.service` and `:`

```
alert($(".service:checked").val());
```