# Break array retrieved from php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Im retrieving an array from php file called check_num.php :-

check_num.php

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';
session_start();
$VALUE = $_SESSION["some_session_variable"];
if(isset($_POST['default'])){
$ert = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE something = '$VALUE' ORDER BY p_id ASC ";
$qty = mysql_query($ert);
$fgh = mysql_num_rows($qty);
$ertz = "SELECT something, COUNT(something) FROM table_name WHERE something = '$VALUE' 
     AND something >= 1 GROUP BY p_id ORDER BY p_id ASC";
$qtyz = mysql_query($ertz);
$tyui = mysql_num_rows($qtyz);
$data = array(
        "post"   => $fgh,
        "likes"  => $tyui
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
  } else {

 echo "0";

  }
?>
```

Now comes the jquery part :-

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    var def = "one";
    $.post("check_num.php", {'default': def },  function(response){
     if(response != 0){

        document.getElementById("total_array_count").innerHTML = response;
        //document.getElementById("total_like_count").innerHTML = response.likes;
        //document.getElementById("total_post_count").innerHTML = response.post;
      ------------------OR THIS Method-----------------
                     var my_array = response;
                     //var post_number = my_array["post"];            
        document.getElementById("total_array_count").innerHTML = my_array;
        //document.getElementById("total_post_count").innerHTML = '<b>'+post_number+'</b>';

        }

        else {


        document.getElementById("total_array_count").innerHTML='Error occured !';

        }
            });

           },2500);
           });
          </script>
```

Now received output is `{"post":10,"likes":1}` , its an array . But when i access array values `response.post` or `my_array["post"]` the value returned is `undefined`.

I had gone through this :- http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_object

And kind of this too:- [jQuery .val() returns undefined for radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691938/jquery-val-returns-undefined-for-radio-button)

Followed it but no success !

Please correct my mistakes .

Comment: `{"post":10,"likes":1}` is JSON, not a javascript object in this case. You didn't tell jQuery to expect json, and your server described the response as text, so jQuery doesn't know that it should parse it to json for you. Set the contentType in php to json and/or set the dataType in $.post to json (it's the last argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `JSON.parse()` on your result before trying to access the values. The result comes as a raw string and you have to convert it to an object first.

```
result = JSON.parse(result);
```

Alternatively, since you're already using jQuery, you can use jQuery's alias for the function.

```
result = $.parseJSON(result);
```

They are essentially the same thing.